# Unable to install the flutter output APK in mobile

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I developed a Flutter app using Android Studio.
If I run the application in the debug mode it's installing and working properly.

I want to install the output apk file on another android mobile.
When I copy the apk file from the output folder and try to install I'm getting an error "Failed to launch installer". I'm installing the app through the file manager.

Please help me to fix the issue.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW5e4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command in terminal

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

and install

```
app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
```

from `project->build/app/output/flutter-apk/`

or
build a release apk and then try to install in device it will work

or

run command `fluter clean` and again run above command and try to install

Comment: tryng to install in real device or emulator ?

Comment: Real device (Nokia 6.1Plus)